# Why does equal sign in string throw unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I only know about this error because I have a Sentry Wrapper in my react app.

I'm trying to understand why an equal sign would throw an exception error in the following context. I am interested in why a comparison operator would be flagged in a string.

I am trying to update state with a string value.

For example

```
this.state = {
      url: ''
}
```

Then later in my component I update that value to:

```
this.setState({
        url: `/?type=all&show=${this.props.show}`,
})
```

This sometimes will trigger a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` error in Sentry

The breadcrumbs lead to a navigation event i.e.

```
to  /?type=all&show=someShow
from    /
```

I am aware of string concatenation as an alternative but I'm interested in finding out why it would be different than say using template strings.

Is there a better way to set string values outside of template literals in JavaScript ?

Comment: when the error is in sentry, is it blank after the second `=` i.e. `this.props.show` had no value at the time?

Comment: @Anthony the props are valid I can see them populated in Sentry's logging on the UI event (click) that triggers this

Comment: You could do `"/?type=all&show=" + this.props.show`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `+` to combine strings before template literals:

```
this.setState({
    url: '/?type=all&show=' + this.props.show
});
```

<strike>But I'm wondering if `this.props.show` is sometimes empty which would result in a bad URL since it would end with `show=` and why you mention this is only sometimes triggered in Sentry.</strike>

EDIT: `show=` is actually valid in URL

Comment: I can see the values in Sentry, and I don't get any undefined errors on those props

Comment: Curious that it doesn't error every time. Have you tried removing the wrapper and seeing if the browser throws an error in the console?

Comment: Ending with `show=` is not a "bad" URL — it's a perfectly valid query parameter which sets "show" to no-value. That can be used anywhere in the query string, including at the end: `example.com?show=&flag=` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @StephenP - updating

Comment: Removing the Sentry Boundary doesnt log anything to the console unfortunately